# Why is this has_many association with dependent: :destroy only destroying the join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have the following classes:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bar_connectors
  has_many :bars, through: :bar_connectors, dependent: :destroy
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bar_connectors, dependent: :destroy
end

class BarConnectors < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
end
```

**more info on my code:** I left out a lot of code that might make the domain more comprehensible... the `Foo`s are joined to each other by a `Bar`, which represents a directionless relationship. The `BarConnector`s point out from the `Bar` to the `Foo`s.

When I call `foo.destroy`, I expect each of its bars to be found and `destroy` to be called on them, which will then in turn destroy each of the `Bar`s `BarConnectors`.

I don't expect `foo.destroy` to be responsible for destroying the `BarConnectors`

What happens is that each `BarConnector` is destroy, but the `Bar` is untouched. (And in fact there are dangling `BarConnectors` that never get destroyed at all, which is the artifact which led me to discover this problem)

Comment: Is this a one to many relationships with foo to bars?

Comment: could you add all the code that you left out to your original question? It'l; make the problem easier to diagnose

Comment: @Sean well, they are huge classes. those are the only `dependent: :destroy`s in the system, if that's interesting. if you tell me what aspects of the classes you are interested in maybe i can provide more relevant info.

Comment: all the relationships would be excellent.  And your intent on the relations ship.  Is foo - bar a many to many relationship or a one to many relationship?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you have a one to many relationship or a many to many relationship.  Before I proceed with how you should solve this, which relationship are you looking to have?